# How to configure Grafana Agent to only skip too old logs?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-agent

I try to use [Grafana Agent](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/) (version 0.35) instead of [Promtail](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/) to send logs to [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/) (version 2.8.4). I want to send Docker container's logs, so I configured `docker_sd_configs`. But after starting Grafana Agent I couldn't find any logs with Grafana. But I  can see an error message in Grafana Agent's logs.

```
Aug 25 10:02:15 test grafana-agent[12795]: ts=2023-08-25T10:02:15.806026191Z caller=client.go:430 level=error component=logs logs_config=default component=client host=172.31.11.242:3100 msg="final error sending batch" status=400 tenant= error="server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request (400): entry for stream '{container=\"keycloak\", host=\"test\", source=\"stdout\"}' has timestamp too old: 2023-08-16T16:20:32Z, oldest acceptable timestamp is:2023-08-18T10:02:15Z"
```

**Configuration**

```yaml
logs:
  configs:
  - name: default

    positions:
      filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

    clients:
      - url: http://172.31.11.242:3100/loki/api/v1/push
        external_labels:
          host: test

    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: docker
      docker_sd_configs:
          - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
            refresh_interval: 5s
      relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
            regex: '/(.*)'
            target_label: 'container'
          - source_labels: [__meta_docker_container_log_stream]
            target_label: source
```

**Research**

- I didn't have the problem with pure Promtail version 2.8.4. At least I didn't notice it.
- I read [Loki/Promtail : parsing timestamp that are too old](https://community.grafana.com/t/loki-promtail-parsing-timestamp-that-are-too-old/41934/2), but I don't want to change Loki's configuration to allow old logs. I just want to skip all too old logs.
- After restarting the Docker containers, Grafana Agent is reading all new logs. But I don't want to restart every container after installing Grafana Agent.
- I read [journal reading: Timestamp too old errors](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/918), but this fix is only for the `journal` configuration.
- I read [Timestamp error](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/7498), but it is not about Docker container logs. Also I didn't find any official documentation about `eventTime`.

**Question**

How to configure Grafana Agent to only skip too old logs?

Answer (score 2):

With the agent in static mode, you would have to find the equivalent in promtail config, which I do not know (see agent [`logs_config`](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/static/configuration/logs-config/#logs_config)).

There is a new way to configure the Grafana Agent, the Flow mode.
Using the Agent in Flow mode you can configure a [`loki.process` with a `drop` stage](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/static/configuration/logs-config/#logs_config) block, here in the context of collecting kubernetes pods logs:

```
discovery.kubernetes "pods" {
  role = "pod"
}
loki.source.kubernetes "pods" {
  targets    = discovery.kubernetes.pods.targets
  forward_to = [loki.process.drop_old.receiver]
}

loki.process "drop_old" {
  forward_to = [loki.write.loki.receiver]
  stage.drop {
    older_than          = "1h"
    drop_counter_reason = "too old"
  }
}

loki.write "loki" {
  endpoint {
    url = "https://logs.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push"
    basic_auth {
      username = ""
      password = ""
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.